# PMSM Rotor Design. Are these terms equivalent?

Tags: motor, synchronous-motor, pmsm, rotor

I'm working on a project with a PMSM. As I go through the literature I come across the following terms and wanted to make sure that I am getting right which ones are synonyms.

Surface-mounted PM = Non-salient pole rotor = Round Rotor = Cylindrical (in this case Inductances \$L_d\$ and \$L_q\$ are equal)

Interior Mounted PM = Buried PM = Salient pole rotor (in this case \$L_q \neq L_q\$)

Is that right?

Comment: When you say 'round rotor' for the surface PM rotor, that means the steel hub, and with magnet arcs of uniform radial thickness. For surface PM rotors with breadloaf-shaped magnets, or magnets that don't cover the full circumference and have positioning nubs on the hub, the Ld and Lq values will still not be quite equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct !

Burried magnet change the permitivity distribution inside the rotor. Thus depending on the arrangement of the magnets, asymetrising its direct and quadratic inductances.

Look at this post: [Explanation of Lq, Ld and how it relates to motor inductance](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/201123/explanation-of-lq-ld-and-how-it-relates-to-motor-inductance)

And this paper (if you can): https://doi.org/10.1109/emobility.2010.5668074